# Jenkins update causes CannotResolveClassException

Tags: jenkins

```
 ---- Debugging information ---- 
 message             : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
 cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
 cause-message       : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
 class               : hudson.model.Hudson
 required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
 converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
 path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
 line number         : 8
 version             : not available

#line #8
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
```

I checked the $JENKINS_HOME/plugins folder. the Project Matrix plugin and the Matrix Auth plugin are there and the manifest says it is compatible with the jenkins version. I've tried manually re-downloading the plugin and putting it in the plugins folder. It gets unpacked, but the class is still is unresolvable.

I also tried reverting back but get the same message.